# Calculate number of weeks in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a formula to calculate the number of weeks and days from a number of days.

For example :

How many weeks and days is 250 days?

How many weeks and days are there from a date until today ?

Note: Calculating *250 days / 7* , then the result is **35.714** , which would be wrong because the decimal can not exceed 6 because after *1,6* must be *2,0*.

Comment: Super User is an English-only site, and all the questions and answers must be in English.

Comment: Ok, thank you DavidPostill, it´s already in English.

Comment: The 0.714 represents 0.714 of a week, or 0.714 weeks * 7 days/week, i.e. 4.998 days. The number would actually be 0.714285714285... but you are only showing 3 decimal places. To avoid using fractions, which can be imprecise on a computer, you can use the MOD function to get the number of days. From [Excel 2007 functions English-Spanish](http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=english-spanish.html), the function is named RESIDUO in Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the old date in **A1**.  In **B1** enter:

```
=INT((TODAY()-A1)/7)
```

in **C1** enter:

```
=(((TODAY()-A1)/7)-B1)*7
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

For a single cell solution use in **B1**:

<strike>=INT((TODAY()-A1)/7) & "," &INT( (((TODAY()-A1)/7)-INT((TODAY()-A1)/7))*7)</strike>

[image]

**EDIT#2**

The correct single cell formula:

```
=INT((TODAY()-A1)/7) & "," & TODAY()-A1-7*INT((TODAY()-A1)/7)
```

[image]

Comment: How can I calculate B1??? The result must be 35,5 in a only cell.

Comment: Ah, ok, I wacthed it now.

Comment: But my excel is in spanish, and it doesn´t know INT.

Comment: @OcnielHernándezEstrada  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Example: in A1: Date: Jan 1st, in B1: Date: Today: Oct 21, in C1: Result 1(Days(293)), in D1: Result 2 (Weeks-Days(41,6)).Today is 41,6, but tomorrow must be 42, not 41,7.

Comment: I have a big problema with INT, my Excel is in spanish, and it doesn´t know INT, (today is hoy), but INT, it has 3 INT, but not INT only, it has INT.ACUM, INT.ACUM.V, INT.EFECTIVO.

Comment: @Ocniel Have a look at [this](http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=english-spanish.html). INT is ENTERO in spanish.

Comment: There´s a mistake: for example: since 01/01/2015 41,5
02/01/2015 41,5,
03/01/2015 41,3,
04/01/2015 41,3,
05/01/2015 41,1,
06/01/2015 41,1,
07/01/2015 41,0,
08/01/2015 40,5,
09/01/2015 40,5,
10/01/2015 40,3,
11/01/2015 40,3,
It repeats 2 times the same result. I don´t know how to upload a picture, I dont watch that opcion. Can you write to my e-mail??? ocniel@ipvce.ss.rimed.cu, I´ll send you a picture. It has to add a day in each date.

Comment: =INT((TODAY()-A1)/7) & "," &INT( (((TODAY()-A1)/7)-INT((TODAY()-A1)/7))*7)
    it has a mistake, repeats 2 times the same result in day differents, example: since 01/01/2015 (41,5) 02/01/2015 (41,5), 03/01/2015 (41,3), 04/01/2015 (41,3), and the correct result would be 41.5, 41.4, 41.3, 41.2, 41.1, 40.0, 39.6. REMEBER: DECIMAL from 0 to 6

Comment: @OcnielHernándezEstrada  See my **EDIT#2** ..................I am sorry for the obvious error.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you all. I´m very happy. Perfect. Thank you all very much.  This is necessary for my job for woman (they are going to have a baby(EMBARAZADAS)) (PARA EL TIEMPO DE GESTACIÓN DE EMBARAZO) =INT((TODAY()-A1)/7)&","&TODAY()-A1-7*INT((TODAY()-A1)/7), IN SPANISH:    =ENTERO((HOY()-A1)/7)&","& HOY()-A1-7*ENTERO((HOY()-A1)/7)    Thanks againg. Bye

Answer (score 1):

The 0.714 represents 0.714 of a week, or 0.714 weeks * 7 days/week, i.e. 4.998 days. The number would actually be 0.714285714285... but you are only showing 3 decimal places. To avoid using fractions, which can be imprecise on a computer, you can use the [MOD](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MOD-function-9b6cd169-b6ee-406a-a97b-edf2a9dc24f3) function to get the number of days. From [Excel 2007 functions English-Spanish](http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=english-spanish.html), the function is named RESIDUO in Spanish.

There is another function to get the whole-number part of division: [QUOTIENT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/QUOTIENT-function-9f7bf099-2a18-4282-8fa4-65290cc99dee) (COCIENTE).

Now we should also convert the numbers we get into text because we want to put in a comma, and also make sure that it shows "0" if there are zero weeks or days. The function to do that is [TEXT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) (TEXTO).

So if we put `250` into cell `A1`, then in cell `B1` we can use the formula

```
=TEXT(QUOTIENT(A1,7),"0") & "," & TEXT(MOD(A1,7),"0")
```

which I think is

```
=TEXTO(COCIENTE(A1,7),"0") & "," & TEXTO(RESIDUO(A1,7),"0")
```

in Spanish.

I don't have Excel to hand, but in LibreOffice:

[image]